# How to store Google credentials in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, storage, google-authentication, oauth2client

How I can store Google credentials in Django model without using oaut2client -> DjangoORMStorage?

Old version with using oaut2client:

```
    storage = Storage(models.GoogleCred, 'act', act, 'credential')
    storage.put(credentials)
```

But oaut2client does not support Django>=2.0